# Why does my shrinkwrap modifier restrict vertice movement over a sculpt that I am trying to retopologize?

Tags: modeling, retopology

For whatever reason, my shrinkwrap modifier is restricting me from moving the vertices where I need them to go for topology. I am trying to retopologize a sculpt, and it's impossible to do with this issue. Maybe I'm missing a step or I screwed something up, but, help would be appreciated.

Here's a gif of the problem (sorry for the terrible quality):
https://i.imgur.com/CFym59J.mp4

Comment: Hmm, looks a bit like snapping is active (but the icon indicates that it is inactive). What happens if you press the Ctrl key while moving around? What happens if you disable the Shrinkwrap modifier?

Comment: When I press the ctrl key it makes the snapping far worse, and when I disable the shrinkwrap modifier it moves normally as it should